# Upload current filepart location instead of given file part location oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Good Day
i have a database which allows the user to upload documents from the system and store the document on the sever which is access by a url as seen below.

Procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE        blob_to_file (p_blob      IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB,
                                              p_dir       IN  VARCHAR2,
                                              p_filename  IN  VARCHAR2)
    AS
      l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
      l_buffer    RAW(32767);
      l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
      l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
      l_blob_len  INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_blob);

      -- Open the destination file.
      l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(p_dir, p_filename,'WB', 32767);

      -- Read chunks of the BLOB and write them to the file until complete.
      WHILE l_pos <= l_blob_len LOOP
        DBMS_LOB.read(p_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
        UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
        l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
      END LOOP;

      -- Close the file.
      UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Close the file if something goes wrong.
        IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
          UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
        END IF;
        RAISE;
    /* WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_operation THEN dbms_output.PUT_LINE('cannot open file invalid name');
    WHEN UTL_FILE.read_error THEN dbms_output.PUT_LINE('cannot be read');
    WHEN no_data_found THEN dbms_output.PUT_LINE('end of file');

    UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
     RAISE;*/
    END blob_to_file;
```

Insert statement to table

DECLARE
l_blob  BLOB;
VID NUMBER;
BEGIN

```
 select  BLOB_CONTENT INTO   l_blob  FROM apex_application_temp_files
         where NAME= :P48_BLOB_CONTENT ;
  
  

  blob_to_file(p_blob     => l_blob,
               p_dir      => 'STOCK_DIRECTORY',
               p_filename => :P48_ATTACHMENT_NAME||'.pdf')
               ;
               
INSERT INTO   ATTACHMENTS(ATTACHMENTS_ID, ATTACHMENT_NAME,CASE_ID,DATE_CREATED, MIME_TYPE,designation)
  VALUES("ATTACHMENTS_SEQ".nextval,:P48_ATTACHMENT_NAME,:P48_CASE_ID,SYSDATE,'application/pdf','http://192.168.XXX.XXX:80/oracle_projects/dppcms/files/'||:P48_ATTACHMENT_NAME||'.pdf');
  
END;
```

What i will like however is to not move the document via the above procedure but to actual store in the attachment table the path of the original file.

so for example if a file is uploaded from the user my documents folder the path stored in the attachment table should show :c\users\mydocuments ect.   instead of using the procedure to send it to http://192.168.XXX.XXX:80 etc

Comment: Not sure this is at all possible. Your browser doesn't have that information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav